# Neo4j statistical data - average of count

Tags: database, neo4j, statistics

I have 2 nodes p:Person and d:DateTime. I need to make statistics : for each hour of the week
Monday 0:
Monday 1:
...
Monday 23:
Tuesday 0:
etc...

Total count is easy

MATCH (p:Person)-[dt:DATE]-(d:DateTime) RETURN d.datetime.dayOfWeek, d.datetime.hour, COUNT(p);

This will output for each hour of week total count, but i need to make average

ex.
10.1.2022 - Monday hour 0 - total count 5000
17.1.2022 - Monday hour 0 - total count 1000
OUTPUT:
Monday 0: 3000;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[:DATE]-(d:DateTime) 
WITH d, d.datetime.dayOfWeek AS day, d.datetime.hour AS hour, COUNT(p) AS count
RETURN day, hour, avg(count) AS average
```

Comment: This outputs something, but i don't thinks it's right, i have 6 milions of date relationships, and it returns average of 20-50 the result should be around thousands for each our of week. And moreover this takes about 17 seconds to do.